# How to select all div element after some specific number of div elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a sample code of my scenario. I have some elements that are loading inside a container div using PHP from a MYSQL table.

```
<div id="itemContainer">
    <div class="item">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

so their may be 10 or 12 items but I need only 4 items to be display at once. so I tried to select all the items after the fourth item. The way I tried has some problems so I need your help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var items = $('#weekly_best_selling').children('.itemContainer').length;
        if (items > 6) {
            $('#weekly_best_selling').children('.itemContainer').nextAll('.itemContainer').css( "background-color", "red" );
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yasithao3/j2zyhmr3/

Comment: you could use .each() [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `:gt` selector to target elements having index greater than the one passed as argument in it. also note that `:gt` selector has 0 based index. Use:

```
$('#itemContainer .item:gt(3)').hide();//hide items having index greater than 3
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6mp563jx/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.item:gt(3)').hide()
```

Use jQuery's `:gt()` selector.