# How to show/hide div element after dynamically loading options in select box inside these div's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadeout

I am having 4 dropdown list inside 4 div's and I want to hide and show this div's on dropdown selection from top to botton. If user changes the option in first dropdown then the immediate next div should be shown and the div's following this next div's should fadeOut().
[situation- Every next Dropdown is filled with options depending on the option selected in parent Dropdown List dynamically]
Now I need the Jquery code as short as possible, hence I tried this....
[How to select all div element after some specific number of div elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647518/how-to-select-all-div-element-after-some-specific-number-of-div-elements)
and made some changes according to my situation.Here is the code....

Html:

```
<div class="wrapper-inner">
    <div class="OrganisationWrapper onChangeHideWrapper" id="OrganisationWrapper" data-title="1">
        @*data-title is used as index for show/hide on Ddl change*@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OrgId, new SelectList(Model.Organisations, "Key", "Value"), "Select Organization..!", new { id = "Organisation", @class = "selectpicker", data_style = " btn-info", data_live_search = "true" })
    </div>
    <div class="SpaceWrapper onChangeHideWrapper" id="SpaceWrapper" data-title="2">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SpaceId, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Loading Space..!", new { id = "Space", @class = "selectpicker", data_style = " btn-info", data_live_search = "true" })
   </div>
......
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#Organisation").change(function () {
    if ($(this).length > 0) {
        index = $(this).parent(".onChangeHideWrapper").attr("data-title");
        $('.wrapper - inner .onChangeHideWrapper:gt(' + index + ')').fadeOut();
    }
    else{
        $('.onChangeHideWrapper').fadeOut();
    }      
}
$("#Space").change(function () {
    if ($(this).length > 0) {
        index = $(this).parent(".onChangeHideWrapper").attr("data-title");
        $('.wrapper - inner .onChangeHideWrapper:gt(' + index + ')').fadeOut();
    }
    else{
        $('.onChangeHideWrapper').fadeOut();
    }
}
```

But fadeOut() is not working. Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanx in advance

Comment: Why don't you create a Fiddle, it would be much easier.

Comment: `$(this).length` is the jQuery object/array length inside those click/change handlers so will always be `1`!

Comment: It would help provide a correct example if you provide the output HTML (as saved from your browser) and perhaps put it all in a JSFiddle. It is not clear from the code (which is broken - see previous comment) what the intended behavior is, so please clarify that too.

Comment: Also your selectors have suffered from bad cut/paste formatting: `.wrapper - inner` = `.wrapper-inner`?

Comment: @skobaljic Cannot create fiddle as it include C# code and I don't know how can I make it work in fiddle. Some data is passes dynamically using Api

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  Got the result it was bad cut/pass
Thanx guys... :)

Comment: @skobaljic I tried same thing in fiddle but its not working
Here's what I want : http://jsfiddle.net/Cijo/ju0p5c0u/11/
Here's what I am trying : http://jsfiddle.net/Cijo/bar95jzq/6/

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle. Working with *output* HTML is much easier for jQuery :) Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this quite a bit if you use operations relative to the changed select.

- You need to initially hide all but the first selector.
- When a select changes, see if the `val()` is the empty string.
- If a selection is made fade in the next div only (using `closest('div').next()`)
- If it is blank, fadeout out all subsequent divs using `nextAll()`

e.g.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.onChangeHideWrapper:gt(0)').hide();
    $('.selectpicker').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            $(this).closest('.onChangeHideWrapper').next().fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.onChangeHideWrapper').nextAll().fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/bar95jzq/8/